# SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path - WAS Liberty 8.5.5.9 Docker

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to start an application that's running on a Docker Container with WAS Liberty 8.5.5.9 (webProfile 7-0) but even though the log says that the server and the application starts sucessfully I got "Context Root Not Found" and the following messages on my log:

SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->rest/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[br.com.lightningtech.api.application.SonoroAPIApplication:[rest/*]], application-->SonoroBluemixApp.

SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/faces/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[Faces Servlet:[/faces/*, *.jsf, *.faces, *.xhtml]], application-->SonoroBluemixApp.

I think this is a conflict issue with some jar. Can someone help me to fix this, please?

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SonoroBluemixApp</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>smoothness</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>        
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>authorizationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>br.com.lightningtech.jsf.filter.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>authorizationFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>paginas/*</url-pattern>
     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

And my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Diging the logs I finally find out that was a ClassDefFound error...
Just needed to add the following dependency to my pom.xml:

 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
 </dependency>